How do I return a 404 page for pagination pages where there are no products?
My website product landing pages have the current pagination:
https://www.example.com/bread/sourdough
https://www.example.com/bread/sourdough?p=2
But if I put in a page number that isn't in the series, like:
https://www.example.com/bread/sourdough?p=123123
Then I still get a live page with 0 products - essentially an empty page.
How do I adjust this to return a 404 when this is the case?
Thanks
